# What is 'pristine' and 'submitting' in reduxForm?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I was going through a simple piece of code in *reduxForm*. What is **pristine** and **submitting**? What is the purpose of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pristine` means that no fields in the form have been modified yet. Perhaps you won't be able to find an exact definition of it in docs, but there is a similar terminology in Angular. You can find some details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp) or [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms).

`submitting`, as the name suggests, means that the form is in process of submitting.

Their typical usage is to disable the "submit" button in case when one of them is true.

Here is an article about Redux Form which you might find helpful: https://alligator.io/redux/redux-form/